# why extra document name "favicon.ico" is present in the mongodb list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

[image]

As you can see in the image, there is two documents name is "favicon.ico", I am new to mongodb and I am playing around CRUD operation, but i am not getting that why this two extra documents are added in the "List" collection even I have not added it.

the following is my get method..it is always called favicon.ico list whenever I request any other list from the DB.

```
    app.get("/:customListName", (req, res) => {
    const listName = req.params.customListName;
    console.log(listName + " list requested")
    List.find().then(function (data) {
        const lists = data;
        var flag = false    ;
        var idx = 0;
        lists.forEach(function (list) {
            if (list.name === listName) {
                flag = true;
                return;
            }
          idx++;
        });

        if (!flag) {
            const list = new List({
                name: listName,
                items: defaultItems
            });

            list.save();
            console.log(listName+" list created successfully...")
            res.redirect("/"+listName);
        }else{
            console.log(listName + " will be render");
             res.render("list",{
                listName: listName,
                newListItem: lists[idx].items,
            });
        }
    })

})
```

So can you please help me on this ? that why it is there ?

[image]

also you can see in this picture that whenever I am calling like "http://localhost:3000/home" (here home is a document inside List collection) after that it is automatically calling and rendering to "http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico", and displaying content of "favicon.ico" document.

I am confused that why it is calling favicon.ico get request ? please help me out on this...